# How to allow user to choose whether or not to

Tags: java, input, output

Here's my code. I know, it's simple, it's around week 4 of this class.

```
    System.out.print("What is your first name? ");

    String first = in.next();

    System.out.print("What is your middle name (If not, just type the RETURN key)?                                      ");

    String middle = in.next();

    System.out.print("What is your last name? ");

    String last = in.next();

    int flength = first.length();

    int mlength = middle.length();

    int llength = last.length();

    int tlength = flength + mlength + llength;

    System.out.println("The total number of characters is: " + tlength);
```

I want to be able to allow users to choose whether to add a middle name or not, but currently my code requires them to enter a middle name. Is there a way to fix this without using if statements? (Which I'm not allowed to use yet)

Comment: Not allowed to use if statements? This must be homework. An if statement is the correct solution, though you could technically solve it with other methods, such as a while loop that never runs more than once.

Comment: @Saposhiente Obviously it's homework.. "it's around week 4 of this class." from the first line. Although I don't really know how that is relevant.... And to comment on the OP's question, I think you need to use if statements to accomplish that.

Comment: What you want is to make a decision - whether or not to enter a middle name. Decision making in programming is achieved with an `if` statement. There may be some workarounds possible but without _really_ trying at it, I don't see a way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that since you can't use an "if" statement, then you can't use a switch on the input either, since that is technically a more advanced concept... But if you can, maybe you could try something like this.

Ask the user if they'd like to enter a middle name, and ask for a "Y" or "N", and store that in a character (char) variable to indicate yes or no.

then, try something like this:

```
switch(charVariable) {
    case 'N': //continue to last name, set middle name to "" or something.
                 break;
    case 'Y': //ask for middle name
                 break;
    default: //this will happen if anything besides "Y" or "N" is input. Maybe assume "no"?
```

I really am not sure how else to do it without an "if" statement.